# Add a row or column to selection Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably super simple but If I already have a selection how can I add the next row without know necessarily what the next one is?

**EDIT**
For example if I have the input range "D1:D8" how can I add in the next row, ie "D1:D9" without putting in "D1:D9".

Comment: The question does not make much sense. Maybe you could elaborate a bit

Comment: @Clauric: question is good and crystal clear. The existing -1 is unfair

Comment: @iDevlop it is now clearer, and makes sense

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Sub inc_row()
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 1, Selection.Columns.Count).Select
End Sub
```

This will increase your selection by 1 row, it will also select the new range

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("b2:f5")
    Debug.Print rng.Address     'returns $B$2:$F$5
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1)
    Debug.Print rng.Address     'returns $B$2:$F$6
End Sub
```